# MySQL return multiple copies of rows with an incrementing count

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a database table to represent a deck of cards, but different cards can have different quantities in the deck. As an example, if the cards represented colors I could have something like:

```
id  | name   | qty
-------------------
1   | Blue   | 5
2   | Green  | 10
3   | Red    | 5
```

I would then want to get 20 rows returned with an extra attribute called card_number ranging from 1-5 for Blues, 6-15 for Greens, 16-20 for Red, etc. I could just use the id field and actually insert 20 rows in the table, but then I run into the problem of modifying the quantity later: if at some point I decide there should be 10 Blues instead, I'd have to redo pretty much all of the id values.

Is there an efficient way to do this in MySQL, or should I just get the base values from the table and then use my server side language (PHP) to build a bigger array? Something like the below, but it feels a little wonky to me.

```
<?php
$cards = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['qty']; $i++) {
    $cards[] = $row['name'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: a regular sql query cannot create rows out of thin air. do this in client-side code.

Comment: @MarcB Why client-side and not server-side ?

Comment: It looks as though your table is modeling the **Deck** as a whole not as a collection of **Card**s - I suspect if you sort out your modeling (Deck, Card, CardToDeck or similar) the problem will resolve itself.

Comment: A query can generate rows from nowhere, but it becomes a mess quickly. Better to do it in the app.

Comment: @Daan This refers to the database client, so php in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer depends on what you want to do with the retrieved data.

Your code:

```
<?php
$cards = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['qty']; $i++) {
    $cards[] = $row['name'];
  }
}
?>
```

Will work. It will create an array consisting of all the cards individually.

Another option would be to do this:

```
<?php
$cards = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  $cards[] = array(
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'qty'  => $row['qty']
  );
}
?>
```

Doing this, you can have a smaller array, and use the `qty` attribute to handle the cards as you want.

Again, it depends on what you want to do with the data. If it's simply mathematical operations, the second option will work fine (using quantity).

Comment: I need to be able to simulate shuffling the deck, drawing a card, and say "This is card number 8, and it is Green." which is why I was assuming I would need the full sized larger array. I suppose it would be possible to use the smaller array and just decrement qty, but I feel the random drawing would be significantly more difficult going that route

Comment: In your situation, I recommend building a full array using the first code option (just `shuffle` and take what's on "top"). This will make handling removed cards from the deck much easier. If you're just wanting to calculate probability, then the second code option would be best since it has a smaller array size. I've built a card game in the past for school using both of these methods.